# DataTable to Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,string>>

Tags: c#, linq, dataset

My DataTable Contains 17 columns, among which i am retrieving 3 columns. For Instance, we consider those 3 columns as colA, colB, colC. My requirement is, the resultant should be in a format of

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,string>> ( Dictionary<colA,Dictionary<colB,colC>> )
```

It would be better using LINQ...!

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> roles = TA_Roles.GetRoleByUsername(Username)
    .Select(col => new { col.RoleID, col.Rolecode, col.Rolename }) 
    //Please continue from here..!
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work if colA is unique:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> result = table.AsEnumerable().ToDictionary(row => row["colA"].ToString(),
                                                                                          row => new string[] { "colB", "colC" }.ToDictionary(col => col, col => row[col].ToString()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>` is not *corrective much* in here because `col1` does not ensure data is unique, you can use `List<Tuple<string, string, string>>` instead

```
 var result = table.AsEnumerable().Select(row => 
                Tuple.Create<string, string, string>(row.Field<string>("col1"), 
                                                     row.Field<string>("col2"), 
                                                     row.Field<string>("col3")));
```

Comment: But colA is the Primary key in the table, i'll refer Dictionary<colB,colC> through colA

Comment: @Praveen:  one data colA just has one data in colB and one data in colC, should not be Dictionary<colB,colC>?

Answer (score 1):

I have two solutions, depending if the col2/col3 combinations are unique or not

```
class Role
{
    public string RoleID { get; set; }
    public string Rolecode { get; set; }
    public string Rolename { get; set; }
}

IEnumerable<Role> source = ...;

Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>> result = source
    .GroupBy(r => r.RoleID)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key,
         g => g.GroupBy(r2 => r2.Rolecode)
        .ToDictionary(g2 => g2.Key,
            g2 => g2.Select(r3 => r3.Rolename).ToList())
    );

// Rolecode unique
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> result2 = source
    .GroupBy(r => r.RoleID)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key,
        g => g.ToDictionary(r2 => r2.Rolecode, r2 => r2.Rolename)
    );
```

But if all the combinations of the three columns are unique, the whole thing is pointless. It would, however make sense to create two dictionaries

```
Dictionary<string, Role> rolesByID = source.ToDictionary(r => r.RoleID);
Dictionary<string, Role> rolesByCode = source.ToDictionary(r => r.Rolecode);
```